# https://www.example.com to https://example.com in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, domains

I've noticed my company's GA is set to www.example.com when they actually only redirect to it from example.com. Should I change to the correct version or does it not impact GA's data collection?

Answer (score 1):

It does not affect data collection in GA, however for the sake of consistency and clarity I would correct the website url in the Property's Setting page and each View's Setting page.

This will also help prevent confusion if/when linking the GA Property to Google Search Console (Google Search Console requires a verified prefix url property to link the two services. In GSC it would need to be the correct domain name and protocol that is being redirected to)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to `Property settings` > `Default URL`. That field is only for preview purposes so it will not affect data collection.

Google Analytics does not store by default the website URL, in case you want this data in your reports you must do it through a `view filter`.